# Is move a keyword in c++?

Tags: c++, keyword, reserved

I'm writing a program and have a function named "move".  But it's highlighted in my codeblocks?  Is move a reserved word in c++?  If so, what does it do?

```
I have it as void move( double t, double u)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not a keyword, but there is a commonly-used standard library function called `std::move`; whoever set up your IDE's syntax highlighting decided to highlight it.

To avoid confusion with people reading your code, it'd be a good idea to call your function something else.

Comment: OP should look into namespaces before deciding to change the name of the function.

Comment: @xboi209 I think it's a good idea to change the name anyway. Just because you *can* call a function move, doesn't mean you *should*

Comment: I agree with @M.M, this used to confused me a lot when I first started programming.

Comment: The reason for having namespaces is so that you can use descriptive names without fear of collision. `std::move` and `physics::move` are obviously two different functions, and unless someone has added the `using namespace std;` abomination there's no reason to worry about someone misunderstanding them.

Comment: What @PeteBecker said is right, as long as all functions are qualified by their appropriate namespaces, using the same name as a standard library function shouldn't matter.